# Listing unpublished posts via Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How does one list draft posts via the Facebook API?  There are endpoints for `published_posts` and scheduled_posts, but nothing for `draft_posts`.  The `posts` endpoint seems to be the same as `published_posts`.

[The Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/) does not seem to mention draft or hidden posts.

[The page/feed documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/page/feed) mentions:

> /page-id/posts shows only the posts that were published by this page.
>
> /page-id/tagged shows all public posts in which the page has been tagged.
>
> /page-id/promotable_posts shows only boostable posts (includes unpublished and scheduled posts). These posts would show the boost button via native UI. Visit our help center to learn why a post may not be boosted.

Which covers everything except unpublished posts which are **not** boostable.

Comment: It seems that by adding a payment method, posts become `boostable` and will then appear under `/page-id/promotable_posts`.  I have not been able determine if there is a way to access unpublished content that is not `boostable`.  Also, I notice that the drafts I create using the Facebook web interface do not get returned via `/page-id/promotable_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the endpoint `/page-id/promotable_posts` to show unpublished posts after I published the Facebook page.

I also tried to add a payment method before publishing (but that did not help).

So try to publish the page, and that should fix this issue.

Logic: `/page-id/promotable_posts` shows only boostable posts and nothing is boostable until you publish your page.

Comment: promototable_posts is deprecated for versions v3.3 and higher